# Assessing the Impact of a Specific Treatment on Survey Results: A Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test Approach on Paired Samples

Tags: nonparametric, survey, paired-data, independence, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have conducted a survey with several scale questions ranked 1-10 on a sample of n=18. I applied a specific treatment before and after the survey. However, I'm unsure about how to analyze the data and determine the minimum sample required to detect a significant change between the survey results before and after the treatment. After considering the circumstances, I believe performing a Wilcoxon signed-rank test for paired samples would be appropriate since the data is not normally distributed and the same sample was used for both surveys. I plan to utilize the R functions ***wilcox.test()*** and ***n.wilcox.ord()*** for this purpose. Have I to perform a test for each question? Do I have to take into account the survey median values to calculate the effect size? Could you please provide me an example and a plot to visualize the results of the two surveys?

Thank you very much! :)

EI_Stats